# How to do "If Clicked Else .."

Tags: jquery, click

I am trying to use jQuery to do something like

```
if(jQuery('#id').click) {
    //do-some-stuff
} else {
    //run function2
}
```

But I'm unsure how to do this using jQuery ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Edit:* I'm trying to run a function if the #id has been clicked and specifically it is has not been clicked then run the function 2 ? i.e. I need to check firstly that the #id has been clicked before running `function2` ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can bind to the click event  either [permanently](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) or as a [one-time event](http://api.jquery.com/one/), and use a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) to see if they've clicked in a specific interval...

Comment: Click is an event. No-Click is constantly happening. How would you know when to execute the else? Please explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Are you trying to see if something was clicked?

Comment: actually, i can't understand how do you want to use it...

Comment: @Tom: Are you confusing "if" for "when"?

Comment: I guess you mean "If clicked elsewhere..."

Comment: thanks guys - added an edit but @JamesLong is what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should avoid using global vars, and prefer using `.data()`

So, you'd do:

```
jQuery('#id').click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

Then, to check if it was clicked and perform an action:

```
if(jQuery('#id').data('clicked')) {
    //clicked element, do-some-stuff
} else {
    //run function2
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: This is another way of writing a global variable btw. Instead of reading/writing it from/to the DOM, reading it from a global hash/object might even be more efficient in this case. Writing it as local state, and reading it like a global from the local DOM element instance itself makes things more confusing for me.

Answer (score 10):

The way to do it would be with a boolean at a higher scope:

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;
jQuery('#id').click(function () {
    hasBeenClicked = true;
});

if (hasBeenClicked) {
    // The link has been clicked.
} else {
    // The link has not been clicked.
}
```

Comment: ah :) cool thanks a lot. learning jQuery so this helps :) will select as the answer when time allows me :) Thanks James!

Comment: We don't know whether the OP wants that set back to `false` when the click is finished. In fact, we're not even sure whether he wants a variable tracking clicked-ness, or an event to fire on click. @Tom, I suggest you go and experiment with it before getting carried away.

Comment: Note that the above code will virtually always run the else case because the click event will not fire before execution reaches the if statement. While this answer may be technically correct, you should make sure that you understand the broader concept of event driven programming.

Comment: As I understand, the `if` needs to be triggered by another event, but even in OP's edit this is unclear.

Comment: @jncraton: Not quite. It's "has the link ever been clicked?", not "is the link being clicked?" For this to really be what the OP wants, he'd have to _already_ have a knowledge of intercepting and cancelling click events on links (or the page would change before his conditional had a chance to run), which is why I'm not at all convinced that this is really what he's after.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - how would I go about setting it back to false after it's been clicked ?

Comment: @Tom: Before I tell you, can you tell me in detail why you want to do that?

Comment: @jncraton - I've +1'd that response because it's a good point. The `if` statement needs to be called by something else. If this is just copied, `hasBeenClicked` will always be false

Comment: @Tomalak That's only true if it's running in a loop, right? This will bind to the click event, and then immediately check to see if the hasBeenClicked is true. The click event isn't likely to fire in that time and actually change hasBeenClicked.

Comment: @jncraton: It's probably actually impossible. It's not just about time duration, but execution order.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - im trying to determine if an 'id' has been clicked and if it has - run 1 function else if it has not run another function ?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var flag = 0;

 $('#target').click(function() {
    flag = 1;
 });

 if (flag == 1)
 {
  alert("Clicked");
 }
 else
 {
   alert("Not clicked");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A click is an event; you can't query an element and ask it whether it's being clicked on or not. How about this:

```
jQuery('#id').click(function () {
   // do some stuff
});
```

Then if you really wanted to, you could just have a loop that executes every few seconds with your `// run function..`

Comment: When posting code, be sure to select it and hit the `{}` button or ctrl+k, or type it out to be indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sarcasm/facetiousness? I was saying it to be a helpful reminder, not to be rude.

Comment: @Brad Christie: I agree, Tomalak is the one being rude

Comment: I'm not being rude at all. I'm pointing out a fact. 10 months is more than sufficient time to learn how to use this website properly without others having to tidy up your posts after you. I'm sorry that I didn't include a smiley.

Comment: You could do this: `$(event.target).hasClass('textbox')`

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Having an "else" doesn't apply in this scenario, else would mean "did not click", in which case you just wouldn't do anything.

Comment: We really need an `onNotClick` event.

Comment: Factually accurate, but doesn't at all address what I fear are serious issues with the OP's imagined use case.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually mean hovering the element by not clicking, right?

```
jQuery('#id').click(function()
{
    // execute on click
}).hover(function()
{
    // execute on hover
});
```

Clarify your question then we'll be able to understand better.

Simply if an element isn't being clicked on, do a `setInterval` to continue the process until clicked.

```
var checkClick = setInterval(function()
{
    // do something when the element hasn't been clicked yet
}, 2000); // every 2 seconds

jQuery('#id').click(function()
{
    clearInterval(checkClick); // this is optional, but it will
                               // clear the interval once the element
                               // has been clicked on

    // do something else
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e)
   {
       if($(e.srcElement).attr('id')=='id')
       {
           alert('click on #id');
       }
       else
       {
            alert('click on something else'); 
       }
   });
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/N6cXQ/)**

You may retrieve a pointer to the clicked element using `event.srcElement` .

So all you have to do is to check the id-attribute of the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

if you press x, x amount of times you will get the division of the checkbox by y which results into a jquery boxcheck which would be an invalid way to do this kind of thing. I hope you will have a look at this before using the .on() functions