# How do I use Jquery's 'on hover' as a conditional?

Tags: jquery

I know that Jquery can do:

```
$('#div').on('click', function() {
    //do something
});
```

What I want to do is check for a click without calling a function in a conditional, something like this:

```
if ($('#div').on('click') && //another conditional) {
    //do something
}
```

Without the function call.  How would I do this?

Comment: you can use the handler function of .on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do "If Clicked Else .."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629297/how-to-do-if-clicked-else)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to just check the condition *inside* your function:

```
$('#div').on('click', function() {
    if(/*condition*/) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

This is the most straightforward way to do this in my opinion.

Also, if you want to use the same element for the conditional statement, you could use `$(this)` inside the function as the selector.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery on hover function does not return a boolean value, only triggers the function that is passed by the second parameter (the first parameter is the action that triggers the function like click).

The only way to use a condition is to use it inside the function:

```
$('#div').on('click', function() {
    if(...) {
        ... 
    }
});
```

You can see the same answer in a similar question:

[How to do "If Clicked Else .."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629297/how-to-do-if-clicked-else/6629427)